# Was there anything different past beating The Legend of Zelda twice?

Tags: nes, the-legend-of-zelda

In the original Zelda things were wildly different on your second playthough. I always wanted to but never managed to keep a NES/Zelda cartridge/battery long enough to go far enough past a 2nd playthough to look for more cool changes.

Did I miss anything?

I could swear before I was old enough to really remember I saw something before I got the NES or Zelda at someone's house that I never found playing it through about 2.5 playthroughs.

Comment: At least in the NES version, you can name your character Zelda, and start immediately at the second quest, without having to beat the first quest.

Comment: To skip to the "Second Quest" immediately, you need to name your file "ZEDA" (all capitals is required!)

Answer (score 14):

No.  To my knowledge, the third playthrough is identical to the second.

The exception is if you're playing the PC clone [Zelda Classic](http://www.zeldaclassic.com/), which does indeed have a third quest.

Comment: @Walter Terrible terrible pun detected.